# Variables Declared in global scope not working

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` with a predefined size. And I have added 2 input fields where in user can type the width and height and on blur it would change the size of the box dynamically via function.It works, only when the 2 variables "custWidth" & "custHeight" are declared inside function and not when declared outside function. Basically these variables store the value typed in the input box.

Now I thought, Variables declared outside function are in Global Scope and function too can use them or is there some other problem?

Below is the link to fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/0tdaxtjt/29/

```
var box = $('#box');
var custWidthField = $('#width');
//var custWidth = custWidthField.val();
var custHeightField = $('#height');
//var custHeight = custHeightField.val();
custWidthField.blur(function () {
    var custWidth = custWidthField.val(); // Not Working When Declared outside function
    // alert(custWidth)
    box.css('width', custWidth);
});
custHeightField.blur(function () {
    var custHeight = custHeightField.val(); // Not working when delared outside function
    //alert(custWidth)
    box.css('height', custHeight);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: if you put `var custHeight = custHeightField.val();` outside of the method then the value of the field is read only once on dom ready.. it will not get updated when the value changes after that

Comment: onDomready in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the declarations or the scope of the variables, it's with the timing of the `fieldname.val()` calls.

If you call `custWidthField.val()` outside the functions, you're just getting the value of the field once, when the document is loaded, before the user has had a chance to enter anything. They won't change when the user fills in the form fields. You need to assign them in the `blur` handler so you get the current value of the form field.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your variable inside the function, you do not need to use `var` again. This is re-setting the scope. Try this:

```
var box = $('#box'),
    custWidthField = $('#width'),
    custHeightField = $('#height'),
    custWidth,
    custHeight;

custWidthField.blur(function () {
    custWidth = custWidthField.val();
    box.css('width', custWidth);
})

custHeightField.blur(function () {
    custHeight = custHeightField.val();
    box.css('height', custHeight);
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0tdaxtjt/34/)

Answer (score 0):

If you define the variables outside the functions they actually are global variables!

The problem is that they're fixed parameters of the first value of the `#height` and `#width` which is empty.

You need to assign the new values for them everytime the function gets executed!